# The constraint GUI is missing from my right toolbar. How to get it back

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I want to add constraints to my widgets without using the XML "Text tab" or "all attributes" option. How do I make it appear again? I have been searching online but could not find a solution.

[image: Missing constraint GUI]

**This is the GUI i'm trying to open up**

[image]

Comment: Try **invalidate and restart** the android studio.

Comment: @Luksprog sorry, i still cant find it. Are you refering to [this part](https://imgur.com/a/O74qZiS)?. Would you be so as to take a screenshot?

Comment: @Zolly first click on imageview or something you want to constraint then click on attributes which you have clicked in first image

Comment: @Jaymin thanks! that worked for me